# How to create a installer to my C# console application(Checkers Game) made in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, dependencies, setup-wizard

**Using Wizard Setup extension**

First I tried to create the installer using **primary output option**, the result is a **application folder without file.exe**(only dll) and the **detected dependencies** is empty (but .Net Core is required)

Second I published my Console app and manually added the files to the installer, it solved the application folder without .exe issue, but the **detected dependencies** still empty (and .Net Core still required).

I already tried to run without dependencies in another machines, but doesn't work

I want to know:
Why it's not detecting dependencies
Or how to manualy put this dependency and how to know what .Net Core version is required

Here is my code for reference(ignore Dama_Console): https://github.com/lincasaires/Practicing-C-

Comment: Do you try to to publish feature in visual studio to make an installer? I have tried it, it works well.